# Down sides of using MergeStrategy.last with SBT Assembly

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

Anybody who tried to use sbt-assmbly to create an uber-JAR to submit as a Spark job has probably wasted a lot of time resolving dependency problems. I have been using the following three methods to do it, and I'd need at least a couple of hours to create a build file that works.. fortunately I can reuse it until I have to add more dependencies or change the Spark version. The methods I use are:

1. When adding the dependency to the libraryDependencies I wrap its entry with a .exclude() or a .excludeAll() call. This is the method described in the [sbt-assembly readme](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/master/README.md)
2. I add an entry to the raw Ivy XML exclusion list. For example, this was necessary for excluding one of the Kafka Jars pulled in by Spark 1.2. I'd do that by adding the following to the build.sbt:

```html
ivyXML :=
  <dependencies>
     <!-- Excluding Original Akke to use the Akka that comes from org.spark-project.akka -->
     <!-- I verified that I actually need that, even though  I am excluding Spark above... AND MLLIB IS PROVIDED -->
    <exclude org="com.typesafe.akka" />
    <!-- Already part of commons-beanutils-core -->
    <exclude org="commons-beanutils" name="commons-beanutils" />
  </dependencies>
```

3. As a last resort I sometimes I have to use assemblyExcludedJars. For example:

```html
assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := 
{  
  val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
  cp filter {j => {
    j.data.getName.startsWith("spark-core") ||
    j.data.getName.startsWith("javax.activation") ||
    j.data.getName.startsWith("commons-collections") ||
    j.data.getName.startsWith("hadoop")
  }}
}
```

Today I stumbled upon a different method which avoids all of this hassle. [This blog post](http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/04/08/creating-uber-jar-for-spark-project-using-sbt-assembly/) proposes using MergeStrategy.first or .last for files within the offending packages. Here is the code:

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
{
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
  case x => old(x)
}}
```

This works, but I don't like how it might result in a set of classes that comes from a mix of two versions. For example, if a class exists in version 1.0 from javax.servlet, but it was deleted in version 1.1 of javax.servlet. This class will not cause a conflict and will be copied over. However, practically the two conflicting classes are usually from the same version, but published under different organizations (eclipse-orbit for example). Therefore, that merge startegy would work very well, and it is much less code and hassle. In fact, I'd prefer risking the tiny probability of facing problems at runtime (when blindly using MergeStrategy.first or .last) to the certain waste of time. What do you think?

Down sides of using MergeStrategy.last with SBT Assembly